# Convert String value into Constant

Tags: php, variables

I have defined a Constant,

```
define("TEST", "good");
```

now I have `$post = "TEST";`

I just wanted to convert this "test" as an constant.

e.g: echo `$post;` it should print `good`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo constant($post);
```

http://php.net/constant

Answer (score 1):

check PHP's `constant()`

http://in.php.net/constant

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes.. That s enough..

```
define("TEST", "good");
$post = TEST;
echo $post;
```

Comment: if the value comes from the database or it is a posted value, then how do you remove the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your definition without quotes like this:

```
define("TEST", "good");
$post = TEST;
echo $post;
```

Comment: if the value comes from the database or it is a posted value, then how do you remove the quotes?